# Through rest service data is inserted successfully in DB but got $http status 0 : ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having issue in rest service in ionic.
I call ionic rest service. My service is called and data is inserted in database..but in ionic after that i got status 0.
How can I solve this? In service as response i set status 201..
If I call this service through rest client then got 201

But in ionic i got 0

Below is my controller

```
    angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('RegService', function($http,$q) {
return{
  insertRegistration: function (reg) {
            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;'
                }
            }



       $http.post("http://XXX:8080/XXX/add/", reg)

             //SUCCESS: this callback will be called asynchronously when the response is available
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Successful: response from submitting data to server was: " + response);
        alert("succ");
               $q.defer().resolve({
                 data: response //RETURNING RESPONSE SINCE `DATA` IS NOT DEFINED
               });
             },

             //ERROR:  called asynchronously if an error occurs or server returns response with an error status.
             function (response) {
               console.log("Error: response from submitting data to server was: " + response);
                  alert("error " + JSON.stringify(response));

               //USING THE PROMISE REJECT FUNC TO CATCH ERRORS
               $q.defer().reject({
                 data: response //RETURNING RESPONSE SINCE `DATA` IS NOT DEFINED
               });

             }
           );
      return $q.defer().promise;
    }
}})
```

It goes in error part...But i checked in DB data is inserted..
How can I solve this problem?
What changes i have to do for success status??

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: error {"data":null,"status":0,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://XXXX:8080/XXX/addXX/","data":"{\"email_address\":\"aaa@aa.com\",\"accountSecretCode\":{\"password\":\"***\"}}","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":""}

Comment: What does the url look like? Is it hosted locally on `localhost`?

Comment: yes on localhost 192.168.XX.XXX:8080/...